# detecting special $2 \times 2$ matrices in a large array of zeros and ones

Tags: matrix, numpy

I have a large array of zeros and ones and I need to count instances of

```
0 1     1 0     0 0     1 1
0 1,    1 0,    1 1,    0 0
```

And I would like to exclude all other $2 \times 2$ submatrices... such as

```
0 1     1 1
0 0,    1 0,    etc.
```

In the space of $2 \times 2$ binary matrices has $2^4 = 16$ elements, and I could like to single out these 4 matrices.  I can't use a linear condition since

```
0 1     0 0   0 1
0 1  +  1 1 = 1 0
```

It is possible to explicitly write a boolean that checks these explicitly, but then I lose the wonderful numpy quickness...

Comment: this looks suspiciously like edge detection, in which case you might find http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html handy

Comment: What do you mean by exclude?  Do you mean adjacent submatrix or arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to rule out adjacent submatrices, you can build an array that represents the $2 \times 2$ submatrices in binary and then check against a list of the valid types.  I.e.,

```
# Represent 2 by 2 submatrices of A in binary
subs = A[::2,::2]+2*A[::2,1::2]+4*A[1::2,::2]+8*A[1::2,1::2]
allowed = ... # List of submatrices to count expressed in binary
for a in allowed:
  print('count %d = %d'%(a,sum(subs==a))
```